# flask socketio CORS

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, cors

I've been trying to send data from flask over socket io. I need to access this data from a different origin, but it is giving a CORS error. I have tried using all kinds of cross origin stuff and none of it has worked. Can somebody help with this.

The view that should be called thought socket io:

```
from flask.ext.cors import cross_origin
@socketio.on('increment',namespace="/api")
@cross_origin()
def increment(message):
    number += 1;
    emit('number',{'data':number},broadcast=True)
```

Running the server:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app,resources={r"/api/*":{"origins":"*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app)
app.debug = True
app.host = '0.0.0.0'

socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: The socket.io events are not normal Flask routes, you can't use regular route decorators like the `cross_origin` from Flask-CORS. I think you need to investigate this problem a little more, CORS support is already implemented in `gevent-socketio`, which Flask-SocketIO uses. Maybe take a look at the requests in your browser's debugger to see where is the error occurring. I just tested cross-origin with the Flask-SocketIO example app and it worked without having to do anything different.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I solved by following:

```py
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
```

Comment: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cors_allowed_origins' i got this error

Comment: I am not getting autocompletion for this as well, this might have been removed for latest versions of the package. Any alternatives that can be used?

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are using the supported version of socket.io in your html file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `cors_allowed_origins="*"` did not work for me. I had to instead specify the full address of the origin as the following:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins=['http://127.0.0.1:5500'])
```

The error message that says `"<client_address> is not an accepted origin. (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level info)"` should indicate which address you should be typing in.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, got it working with this setup:

```python
#you may not need all these options
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room
from flask.ext.cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./', static_folder='./', static_url_path='')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some-super-secret-key'
app.config['DEFAULT_PARSERS'] = [
    'flask.ext.api.parsers.JSONParser',
    'flask.ext.api.parsers.URLEncodedParser',
    'flask.ext.api.parsers.FormParser',
    'flask.ext.api.parsers.MultiPartParser'
]
cors = CORS(app,resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app)
socketio.run(app,port=5000,host='0.0.0.0')
```

You can set up routes as such:

```python
@app.route("/")
def indexRoute():
    return render_template('index.html',version=VER)
```

And socket requests:

```python
@socketio.on('connect',namespace="/home")
def test_connect():
    print "client connected:",rooms()[0]
```

On the client side in JS i did the following:

```javascript
var socket = io.connect('http://' + location.hostname + ':5000/home');
socket.on('connect',function(data) {
    console.log('connected to socket');
});
```

Also, take a look at [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/) snippet from Flask developers.